# How to write this query in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

[image]

This table is showing that

- `Emp 1` has worked for 7.0 hours on `Project 1` on 14/1/2010.
- `Emp 2` has worked for 8.0 hours on `Project 2` on 15/1/2010.
- `Emp 1` has worked for 8.0 hours on `Project 1` on 16/1/2010.

I want to update that table like this:

- I want to update the column [14 Jan] column first row with 7.0 for Emp 1
- I want to update the column [15 Jan] column second row with 8.0 for Emp 2
- I want to update the column [16 Jan] column third row with 8.0 for Emp 1

Hence the result should be:

[image]

Can anybody please suggest me how to write the query for the same in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: Are you sure that you need this not normalized columns? You can [pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) your data to get it with out denormalize.

Comment: Hi danihp, Thanks for your comment. Since, I have to display the Result as a Report, I don't need normalized columns.
Can you suggest me how can i use Pivot concept to work on this requirement?

Comment: If pivot approach is a solution for you, I suggest to you that edit answer and inform about it, in this way someone can write select quickly. Your actual question it is really easy with a case statement but I think people don't like table schema and this can be the reason for no answers.

Answer (score 0):

H got a very nice reply from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1857224.aspx/1?How+to+write+this+Update+Query+in+SQL+Server+2005+)